# How to make a autoclicker inside of roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

My friend has recently been making a fighting game and wants to make an autoclicker for it. He is using the official default roblox sword for the sword, but can't find any ways to make it go constantly. We tried to make an autoclicker that would click normally but Lua doesn't have and good ways to do it. Can someone please help me fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the event in the code that runs when the mouse is clicked, and make it a function.

From there, make it so that if the autoclicker is enabled, the event is run every amount of time you'd like, using wait.